# Ubuntu 13.04 64bit unity desktop Freezing

Tags: unity, 13.04, compiz

The Screen freezes with the exception of movement by mouse, I went to a virtual tty with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> and reran Unity which unfroze the desktop.

This is the tail of my /var/log/syslog:

```
praveen@praveen-XPS-L412Z:~$ tail -f /var/log/syslog
Jun 10 11:17:01 praveen-XPS-L412Z CRON[25625]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun 10 11:22:15 praveen-XPS-L412Z kernel: [ 6184.595684] [drm:i915_hangcheck_hung] *ERROR* Hangcheck timer elapsed... GPU hung
Jun 10 11:22:15 praveen-XPS-L412Z kernel: [ 6184.595690] [drm] capturing error event; look for more information in /debug/dri/0/i915_error_state
Jun 10 11:23:17 praveen-XPS-L412Z gnome-session[7781]: WARNING: Application 'compiz.desktop' killed by signal 9
Jun 10 11:23:17 praveen-XPS-L412Z gnome-session[7781]: WARNING: App 'compiz.desktop' respawning too quickly
Jun 10 11:23:17 praveen-XPS-L412Z gnome-session[7781]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Jun 10 11:23:18 praveen-XPS-L412Z gnome-session[7781]: WARNING: App 'compiz.desktop' respawning too quickly
```

Please let me know about a permanent fix as this recurs.

Comment: I got this error with Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit, and fixed it with `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` installing everything it recommended, and rebooting.